Finding Issuer Data on x509 Certificate
We've generated a Key Pair/Certificate using Keystore Explorer. This is self-signed by following these steps:

generate csr from the generated cert;
sign the csr using the generated cert;
import the signed csr (aka the ca reply) on the generated cert;

This cert is for internal use alone but we did this self-signing anyway for reasons described HERE as a good practice.
My attempt to visually distinguish between a certificate that's self-signed, like the one above, and another that's unsigned, for its issuer properties isn't positive. Perhaps this is encoded within, in a machine readable form. So, the question is, does the self-signed certificate has an indication visible or printable using OpenSSL or Java for example that it was signed by its own (or anyone for that matter)?

A self-signed cert has Issuer name equal to Subject name, and if the SubjectKeyId and keyid form of AuthorityKeyId extensions are present (now common, but not required) they are also equal. Both of these are commonly available from all cert-handling software. For OpenSSL commandline run openssl x509 -text [-noout] <$file and for Java commandline run keytool -printcert -file $file, but these are offtopic for SO. For OpenSSL (including LibreSSL or BoringSSL) code call X509_get_{subject,issuer}_name etc and for Java code call X509Certificate.get{Subject,Issuer}X500Principal etc. ...

... Or if you mean the Java KeyStore Explorer at keystore-explorer.org, that already displays both names. Moreover, creating a keypair with that program, or with Java keytool -genkey[pair], ALREADY created a self-signed certificate and you didn't need to do anything else at all. As described on the Q you link, there cannot exist an unsigned X.509 certificate (although there can exist one whose signature is unimportant).

@dave_thompson_085 - thx, if the generated cert via keystore-explorer.org is already self-signed then how does it still allow importing a ca reply issued by a valid public ca, that is, if I choose to go that route?

You can always import (with either keytool or KSE) to a privatekey entry a valid cert or chain if it matches that key, which a (nonerroneous) CA reply always does, and it replaces whatever was there before, including if what was there before was the autogenerated selfsigned cert.

please transfer this comment to an answer and I shall mark it an answer, thx
